# "Voice trigger" detection

Tags: speech-recognition, signal-processing, voice, voice-recording

I have a voice application that would be much-improved if there was the ability to use a "trigger word" to start recording audio. I don't need a full speech-text engine, just the ability to reliably/efficiently detect the trigger word.

I am wondering if there are any specialized speech engines that support this specific use case, or any libraries/methods to developing such a single-purpose detection engine. Ideally I'd like it to work in noisy environments, but it can be trained for a single user's voice.

Pointers to research papers / topics would also be appreciated so I know what to ask for.

Comment: Does it have to be spoken words?  A clap or whistling a tune would be a lot easier.

Comment: please share link of your project if it is open source, I am working on a similar project

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine on the Red5 project created a similar demo using trigger words to cause a search to be run against an image repository. Saying "cat" caused an image of a cat to appear within about a second. The client application was written in Flash and the back-end ran on Red5 using the free Sphinx library. You could certainly do what you want with Sphinx without much effort.

Sphinx project: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I could be completely off, but using a full featured speech-recognition library may be overkill for your use-case..

If you can live with something simpler but still audio driven consider this:

Detecting a hand-clap is very simple. A hand-clap will have high energy over the overall audio band. Detecting it is simple and much cheaper computational wise than full-bown speech recoginition.

In a nutshell you record the audio, do a (short time) FFT on the data and detect the case where you have high energy in 80% of the available frequency bins. 80% takes care of any phasing issues due to a simple recording-room/microphone setting. Then adjust the thresold to taste and you're done.

Doing the same with speech-recognition is possible as well, but you will burn *tons* of CPU cycles.

Comment: This is very interesting. But could you detect language this way? Is that how "hey Siri" and "OK Google" do it?

Answer (score 0):

What O/S? I wonder for example whether [Speech functionality in Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Application_Programming_Interface#Speech_functionality_in_Windows_Vista) would help you. Recognising a single word seems like the simplest possible problem for any speech analyzer.

Comment: Recognizing a single phrase would be easier. The longer the key word or phrase to be recognized is, the easier it is to avoid false positives. That's why finite-grammar recognition is much easier and more reliable than dictation.

Answer (score 0):

There were asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877508/need-text-to-speech-and-speech-recognition-tools-for-linux/) just a few days ago about speech recognition possibilities on linux. What you ask for is a subset of that, I assume some of those answers could contain useful information. The article linked in joeforker's answer was very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a voice recording win32 app.  I use an OCX to manage recording/playback.

I know it is not exactly the solution you are asking, but you might want to consider a foot pedal.  It is simple to program and would serve very much like a spoken word to begin/stop recording.  Check these:  www.pedalpower.com

Hope it helps,

Reinaldo.